# how to pause execution on error in cucumber ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I want the test suite to pause when an error is thrown so that I can debug in the browser, like how chrome devtools allows you to pause on error. I tried using an Around block to catch the error and start a debug session but the error must be getting caught before it bubbles up to this level because the rescue is never triggered.

```
require 'pry-nav'

Around do |_scenario, block|
  begin
    block.call
  rescue Exception, StandardError, Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError, RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError, Capybara::ElementNotFound => e
    puts e
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

How do I stop the execution?

Answer (score 0):

Use byebug.

When you get an error, use the error message to

1. get the scenario causing the problem (so you can run it on its own)
2. get a starting point to start debugging, which will be above where the error occurs.

There isn't much point in debugging at the point of the error because most errors occur when an assertion fails and you will just be in a pile of complex test framework code that has nothing to do with your application, and is already past the point of failure

Comment: I could swap pry out for byebug but it wouldn't change the fact that it is never reached so execution never stops. The goal isn't to use the debugging tool to get more info, it's to leave the browser open at the time the assertion failed and allow me to run more commands.

Comment: my point is by the time the assertion fails the interesting stuff is past. You can use Pry or Byebug that doesn't matter. But in general with a well written scenario that is failing you have to debug from the When that prompts the action, By the time you get to the Then that is failing you are past the problem code.